# Активный пункт в меню вордпресс

Tags: wordpress, cms

Как добавить класс активного пункта меню. Вызываю меню так

```
  <?php 
          $menuParameters = array(
              'container' => 'nav',
              'container_class' => '', 
              'menu_class' => '',
              'echo' => false,
              'items_wrap' => '%3$s',
              'theme_location' => 'menu_top'
            );

            echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters ), '<nav><a>' );
           ?>
```

на сайте выводится так

```
<nav class="menu-menyu-v-shapke-container"><a href="http://site.org/soderzhanie">Содержание</a>
<a href="http://site.org/zarabotok">Заработок</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Уберите название сайта, выглядит как спам

Comment: а как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Класс активного пункта меню `current-menu-item` добавляется в `<li>`, а вы его выкинули с помощью `strip_tags()`. Пункт меню с активным классом выглядит примерно так:

```
<li id="menu-item-700" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat current-menu-item menu-item-700"><a href="https://site.org/product-category/transivers/">Трансиверы оптические</a></li>
```

Замените строку вывода на такую:

```
echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters ), '<nav><a><li>' );
```

Comment: а без li никак?

Comment: Никак. А что за проблема? Исправьте вид li через css, если что-то не нравится

Comment: исправил, вернул ul обратно, спасибо

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

```
// for custom menus 
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'normalize_wp_classes', 10, 2);

// for the page menu fallback (wp_list_pages)
add_filter('page_css_class', 'normalize_wp_classes', 10, 2);

/**
 * @param  $classes array
 * @param  $item object
 * @return array
 */
function normalize_wp_classes(array $classes, $item = null){

  // old classes to be replaced with 'active'
  $replacements = array(
    'current-menu-item',
    'current-menu-parent',
    'current-menu-ancestor',
    'current_page_item',
    'current_page_parent',
    'current_page_ancestor',
  );

  // if any of the classes above are present,
  // return an array with a single class ('active')
  return array_intersect($replacements, $classes) ? array('active') : array();
}
```